# Checking confidence intervals on user defined contrast (one-way ANOVA)

Tags: r, anova, confidence-interval, contrasts

Hi is anyone able to help - I am doing this all in R Code:

I have run one way analysis on some data and set up 2 contrasts (Liberarts-Finearts and also Engineering-science). I now need to calculate the 90% confidence level for each contrast in my user defined contrast. Please can anyone advise if what I have done so far is correct and also how to calculate the 90% confidence level for each of the 2 contrasts?

The data and code used so far is;

```
    Aptest<-data.frame(Scores,Degree) #Data frame
    Aptest
    Scores      Degree
    1      49    Business
    2      34    Business
    3      45    Business
    4      59    Business
    5      74    Business
    6      53    Business
    7      51    Business
    8      57    Business
    12     85     Science
    13     79     Science
    14     91     Science
    15     60     Science
    16     72     Science
    17     50 Liberalarts
    18     41 Liberalarts
    19     65 Liberalarts
    20     57 Liberalarts
    21     62 Liberalarts
    22     47 Liberalarts
    23     59 Liberalarts
    24     48 Liberalarts
    25     37    Finearts
    26     26    Finearts
    27     52    Finearts
    28     39    Finearts
    29     44    Finearts
    30     50    Finearts
    31     41    Finearts
    32     35    Finearts
    33     88 Engineering
    34     70 Engineering
    35     95 Engineering
    36     77 Engineering
    37     81 Engineering
    38     89 Engineering
    39     62 Engineering
    40     83 Engineering

    #Set up appropriate contrasts in R to analyse and report on differences between
    Liberalarts-Finearts and also Engineering-Science

    mat = matrix(c(0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1),ncol =2) #Initial contrast matrix
    mat
    [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    0    0
    [2,]    0   -1
    [3,]    1    0
    [4,]   -1    0
    [5,]    0    1

    my.contrasts = mat %*% solve(t(mat) %*% mat)

    my.contrasts
    [,1] [,2]
    [1,]  0.0  0.0
    [2,]  0.0 -0.5
    [3,]  0.5  0.0
    [4,] -0.5  0.0
    [5,]  0.0  0.5

    contrasts(Aptest) = my.contrasts #Assigning contrasts

    contrasts(Aptest)
                [,1] [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
    Business     0.0  0.0 -0.80710330 -0.3854663
    Engineering  0.0 -0.5 -0.01370638  0.5475510
    Finearts     0.5  0.0  0.41725803 -0.3548179
    Liberarts   -0.5  0.0  0.41725803 -0.3548179
    Science      0.0  0.5 -0.01370638  0.5475510

    summary.lm(aov(Scores~Degree)) #Summary of Scores~Degree

    Call:
    aov(formula = Scores ~ Degree)

    Residuals:
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
   -18.7500  -4.3750   0.3125   6.5312  21.2500 

   Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   (Intercept)         52.750      3.637  14.503 1.51e-14 ***
   DegreeEngineering   27.875      5.144   5.419 8.83e-06 ***
   DegreeFinearts     -12.250      5.144  -2.382 0.024279 *  
   DegreeScience       22.250      5.144   4.326 0.000175 ***
   ---
   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

   Residual standard error: 10.29 on 28 degrees of freedom
   (8 observations deleted due to missingness)
   Multiple R-squared: 0.7417,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.714 
   F-statistic:  26.8 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 2.225e-08
```

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since `Aptest` is a data frame I wonder what `contrasts(Aptest)` means. The `contrasts` function is not defined for data frames. Do you mean `contrasts(Aptest$Degree)`?

Answer (score 3):

It appears, your contrast isn't used by the `aov` function. You have to specify the contrast with the `contrasts` parameter in `aov`.

```
myAOV <- aov(Scores~Degree, Aptest, contrasts = list(Degree = my.contrasts))
```

Have a look at the summary. It displays the results for the two contrasts:

```
summary.lm(myAOV)

Call:
aov(formula = Scores ~ Degree, data = Aptest, contrasts = list(Degree = my.contrasts))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-26.584 -13.584  -3.343  14.854  38.051 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   59.146      2.961  19.975   <2e-16 ***
Degree1      -13.125      8.921  -1.471    0.150    
Degree2      -12.394      9.991  -1.241    0.223    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 17.84 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.09823,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.04518 
F-statistic: 1.852 on 2 and 34 DF,  p-value: 0.1724
```

Once you have the object returned by the `aov` function, it's easy to compute confidence intervals with the `confint` function:

```
confint(myAOV, level = 0.90)

                  5 %      95 %
(Intercept)  54.13929 64.153083
Degree1     -28.20974  1.959744
Degree2     -29.28789  4.499750
```

Comment: Hi, that is great thank-you - I seem to have misunderstood how to do this, but I believe your answer will help so I'll try it later!  Thanks alot

Comment: Hi, I've tried this to specify the contrasts as you suggested but am getting the error:Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows    Do you have any idea why this is erroring?  Thanks

Comment: @TanyaKiddle How many levels does your factor have? How did you create the contrast matrix?

Comment: 5 levels                                               Scores<-c(49,34,45,59,74,53,51,57,77,65,71,85,79,91,60,72,50,41,65,57,62,47,59,48,37,26,52,39,44,50,41,35,88,70,95,77,81,89,62,83)

Degree<-c(rep('Business',8),rep('Science',8),rep('Liberalarts',8),rep('Finearts',8),rep('Engineering',8))

Aptest<-data.frame(Scores,Degree)
mat = matrix(c(0,0,1,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1),ncol =2)              mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0   -1
[3,]    1    0
[4,]   -1    0
[5,]    0    1

my.contrasts = mat %*% solve(t(mat) %*% mat)

Comment: Hi Sven - I've now gotten this to work - thanks alot for your help with this.  Thanks

Comment: @TanyaKiddle If thins answer helped solving your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.